# Silverlight - Copy files directly into where Isolated Storage physically store files

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

In our Silverlight business application, we need to cache very large files (100's MBs) into isolated storage. We distribute the files separately to be downloaded by users and then they can import those files into Isolated Storage through the application.

However, the Isolated Storage API seem to be very slow and it takes an hour to import about 500MB of data. 
Given, that we're in a corporate environment where users trust us, I would like users to be able to copy the files directly into the physical location on their file system where Silverlight store files when using the API.

The location varies per OS, but that's ok. The problem however, is that Silverlight seems to store files in a somewhat cryptic way. If I go to my AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is, I can see some weirdly named folder that look like long Guid.

My question: is it possible to copy files directly in there, or is it going to upset Silverlight ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been testing it will make stuff fail/act weird. We had some stuff we had to clear and even though we did delete the files to test how it worked the usedspace didn't drop. So there is some sort of register of which files are in IS and how big they are.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be paramount you find out why IS is so slow.  Can you confirm its like that on all clients?  Test some others.  This should be brought up to Microsoft if it is the case.  Possibly you can change your serailization schema and save smaller files?  I would not advise trying to figure out Microsoft's temporary and volatile IS storage location.